# Why does as.list() applied to a vector generate a list that is not treated the same as a list generated with list() in R?

Tags: r, list, loops, output

Here is a very basic example that illustrates the differences in R

Given the following  data frames:

```
a <- data.frame(l=c("object1", "object2"))
b <- data.frame(l=c("object3", "object4"))
```

Creating a vector for the names of the data frames:

```
 vector <- c("a","b")
```

And then applying `as.list()`

```
list_of_vector <- as.list(vector)
```

If we try loop this:

```
lapply(list_of_vector, print)
```

The output is

```
[1] "a"
[1] "b"

[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"
```

Compared to just manually creating a list and then running the same loop:

```
straight_list <- list(a,b)
lapply(straight_list, print)

        l
1 object1
2 object2
        l
1 object3
2 object4
[[1]]
        l
1 object1
2 object2

[[2]]
        l
1 object3
2 object4
```

I would like to understand what makes `as.list()` different from `list` and how I would be able to convert a vector like the above to create the 2nd, rather than first output. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have a typo, which is why: `vector <- c("a","b")` should be `vector <- c(a,b)`

Comment: How can I turn a vector with the speech marksk into one without them

Comment: If you have a character vector with the intent to retrieve all of its objects, then `mget(vector)` in your case may do what you want. If not, I suspect I don't understand ...